# MouseDrag drawing a Square not working as intended

Tags: java

```
 @Override
    public Shape getShape() {
        final Rectangle2D.Double result = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        result.setFrameFromDiagonal(getStart(), getEnd());
        //FIX this is causing square to move when going opposite direction  
        result.setRect(result.getX(), result.getY(),
                       result.getHeight(), result.getHeight());
        return result;
    }
```

So here is my code that is drawing a square using Rectangle2D.Double. The getStart() and getEnd() are points that are being returned from mouseDrag events. When I drag to the right or up, it works as intended and creates a square. When I drag left or down the square moves with the drag as it draws. I am fairly new to Java swing and paint components. Wondering if anyone know what is causing this and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider a few specialities:

1. Save the first coordinate on mouse click: x,y
2. Save the last coordinate on mouse drag x2,y2
3. Set min x and y coordinates as the startpoint for setRect: Math.min(x,x2);
4. Use the absolute value of the coordinate difference to calculate the height and width of rectangle: Math.abs(x-x2);

---

```
px = Math.min(x,x2);
int py = Math.min(y,y2);
int pw=Math.abs(x-x2);
int ph=Math.abs(y-y2);
result.setRect(px, py, pw, ph);
```

Comment: I see the reasoning here now, but this does not lock the square into square dimensions, since it is using rectangle the square is draggable out of width and height, causing it to become a rectangle instead. Is there a way to utilize what you just posted but lock the height or width?

Comment: You can use pw or ph for both height and width just like you're doing it now. A square is just a rectangle with the same width and height. `result.setRect(px, py, pw, pw);`

Comment: Thanks. Works great now.

Comment: One more thing, not working as intended. When I drag the Square or Circle tool down or right it works fine, when I drag it up or left, the shape moves with the cursor. Is there a way to lock that down?